# Not Working: Add a Project to Team Foundation Server 2012 using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs, azure-devops

I am trying to add new projects to the Team Foundation Server and every way I have tried to add them has failed.  We are running TFS 2012 Version: 11.0.50727.1 (RTM) and I am running Visual Studio 2015.  I am a member of the Administrators Group.

I have tried at least 3 ways that MS support says how to do it on the website and none of them have worked:

1. I have tried to add it through Visual Studio
2. I have tried to add it through the Team Foundation Server Administration Console on the Server.
3. I have tried to add it through the TFS Web Management Portal.

When I try to add it through Visual Studio, I get an error when trying to check it in.  It shows on the Source Control Explorer with a pending change of 'Add'.  Here is a screenshot of the team explorer and output:
[image: Visual Studio Error When adding New Project]

Since the message tells me to add it to the server, I opened the TFS Server Admin Console and When I go into the Team Projects Tab under Team Project Collections, it lists the existing projects, however, there is no way to add a new project.  Here is a screenshot of the Admin Console:

[image: TFS Admin Console Team Projects]

There is only a help icon with a link on How to add a Team Project, although like with most MS help articles, it is useless.  It provides information about how to do it on the web.  So I tried it.  I accessed the web portal for our TFS server and there isn't any option to add a project there either.  When I go in to the "View the collection administration page"   It tells me "Not all Collection level administration is exposed in the web experience. For all administration operations at the collection level please use the Administration Console on your Team Foundation Server.".  Here is a screenshot of the online portal:
[image]

Can someone please help me with this issue?  How can I add the projects to the Team Foundation Server?

Comment: Can you try to do this with VS2012&Team Explorer 2012?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how to Add the projects to the Team Foundation Server using Visual Studio 2015.  It is very simple and can be done right from the File Menu in Visual Studio.

1. First open Visual Studio 2015. (I am not sure if it works the same in other versions.)
2. Go to **File -> New -> Team Project...**
   [image]
3. The New Team Project Wizard will popup where you can then enter the project name and project description.
   [image]
4. Then you can choose the template type and whether you will be using TFS Version Control or Git Distributed Version Control.
5. Once you click Finish, the Project will be added to TFS.
6. You can then add the files to the workspace folder on your dev machine.
7. Then you can check the files into TFS using the Team Explorer.  *Note: First, you may need to add the files to the project by going to the Solution Control Explorer and right clicking on the newly created project and selecting Add Items to Folder.  From there you can add the files then check them in using the Team Explorer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Please clarify you want to create a code project/solution and add it to a TeamProject, or you want to create a TeamProject. TeamProject and code project/solution are different.
2. If you want to create a new TeamProject, according to [Client compatibility](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/requirements#client-compatibility), TFS 2012 supports VS 2015 RTM or latest update. Check your VS 2015 edition and re-try to [create a TeamProject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181477(v=vs.110).aspx).
3. If you want to add a code project/solution to a TeamProject, you'll have to connect a TeamProject first and create a workspace, then perform a check-in: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/set-up-team-foundation-version-control-your-dev-machine
4. Last, try to clean the Cache folder on your dev computer. The folder path is: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache`.
5. If none of above works, try on another dev machine to see whether you can reproduce this issue.

Comment: I have tried them.  The Cache folder was already clear.  There was a 6.0 folder that has files in it.  I figured out how to add the project to TFS though a different way that worked using Visual Studio and I will add that answer here.  I even updated to TFS 2015 as part of the process and that didn't really change much.